# Memory error after updating Ubuntu

Tags: unity, virtualbox, xorg, 17.10

The instruction at 0x00000000019BFCAE referenced memory at 0x00000000A6C81001. The memory could not be read.

Click on OK to terminate the program.

My development environment is run on Oracle VM Virtualbox and I decided to update my Ubuntu to 16.10. It will get to the login screen but then it breaks given the aforementioned error.

There is a setting at the login screen that has the options Ubuntu on Xorg or Unity. I found that if I used Unity I received no error but I always get the error immediately after logging in.

Comment: Do you see this error after starting Virtualbox, or starting the guest OS, or at some other time?

Comment: After I type my password and hit enter to log in the screen goes black and, after a few seconds, I get the error. When I hit enter the VM shuts down.

Comment: Do other guest OS's work, or is it just this one that fails? Can you start it in recovery mode?

Comment: I don't use any other OS, so I don't know. I can get it to start if I change the setting from Ubuntu on Xorg to Unity at login. I just want to know WHY that works.

Comment: You might try changing the memory allocated to the video card in the VM. There is a GRUB setting that allows you to map out bad memory, but rather than try that, I'd recommend going to memtest86.com and downloading the free memory test and running that on your system.